Overwriting and deleting linked list elements
I was solving following leetcode problem, where given a linked list, you're supposed to remove all the ListNodes that have a certain value val.
I know the best solution is to directly remove the nodes from the list, but I tried something different:
public ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
    // copy wanted values from linkedlist into list
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ListNode current = head;
    while (current != null){
        if (current.val != val){
            list.add(current.val);
        }
        current = current.next;
    } 

    // overwrite the values of the first few nodes
    current = head;
    for(Integer num : list){
        current.val = num;
        current = current.next;
    }

    // disconnect the last node from the remaining ones
    current.next = null;
    return head;
}

So for example if list (1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5) is given with val=3:
At first I save all the values that aren't 3. Then I overwrite the same list (1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 5) and then I delete the pointer to the remaining nodes (1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5).
I know the problem asks to remove the nodes and not to overwrite them, but since I'm not supposed to solve in place I figured it shouldn't matter.
But this doesn't work: The first nodes are always correct, but there are almost always nodes from the original list which should have been disconnected. And I don't know why setting the last pointer to null doesn't get rid of them.
I know that this isn't how you're supposed to solve this problem, but I can't figure out why it shouldn't work this way.

I think that after the for loop, current is pointing to one node past the end.

You should try stepping through this in a debugger

@001 you are right. I added an if statement for when the arraylist is empty and an if statement in the for loop to cut the list off. It passed all the tests (:


But this doesn't work: The first nodes are always correct, but there are almost always nodes from the original list which should have been disconnected. And I don't know why setting the last pointer to null doesn't get rid of them.

You should really learn to use a debugger.  It's an invaluable tool for figuring out what's actually going on in a program.  If you're using an IDE then it surely has an integrated one.
Alternatively, if you want to analyze code without running it, then start with very simple cases.  For example,

an empty list
a single element list

where the element needs to be removed
where it does not need to be removed


etc.

Let's think about the empty list case, which I'll assume is conveyed by head being passed in as null.  Your code will successfully extract all zero elements' values into list, but look what happens when you go to write those values back out (annotations added as comments):
    current = head;  // 'head' is null, so this is equivalent to current = null;

    for(Integer num : list){ // 'list' is empty, so no iterations are performed
        current.val = num;
        current = current.next;
    }

    // disconnect the last node from the remaining ones
    current.next = null;  // 'current' is still  null, so kapow! NullPointerException

In case the nature of the issue is not yet clear, that should at least tell you that it has something to do with current when you truncate the list. I trust that with a little thought, you will recognize that current always refers to the node after all that have already been accepted to remain in the list.  It is the first one that needs to be truncated, not the last one that needs to be kept, and assigning current.next = null does not truncate it.  (Neither would current = null.  You'll have to be cleverer than that.)
Actual solution is left as an exercise.

Well I can relate with you so much,while solving a question we get so obsessed with our own logic of solving the question that we can accept that there is a another way.
Here the is the Actual solution :
I think instead of direct nulling the current note ain't a solution ,we have to keep track of the previous node and only check that previous node is not and simply with make previous of next null thats it!
Actual Code

public ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {
    // Copy wanted values from linked list into a list
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    ListNode current = head;
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.val != val) {
            list.add(current.val);
        }
        current = current.next;
    }

    // Overwrite the values of the first few nodes
    current = head;
    ListNode prev = null;
    for (Integer num : list) {
        current.val = num;
        prev = current; // Keep track of the last node where we set the value
        current = current.next;
    }

    // Disconnect the remaining nodes
    if (prev != null) {
        prev.next = null;
    }

    return head;
}

I may be wrong , Just inform that its correct or not!
Hope it helps!

Why are you copying the whole linked list to a list? You can just run through the whole linked list, you gotta keep track of the next two nodes. If the next value is equal 3, you point the current node to the next_next value, (that's why you need the next two values) and do that recursively until you traverse the whole linked list.

OP has acknowledged that they "know the best solution is to directly remove the nodes from the list, but I tried something different"
